# How to Invalidate only part of a paintbox/bitmap to optimise its performance?

Tags: delphi, lazarus

The question relates to: [Drawing on a paintbox - How to keep up with mouse movements without delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509235/drawing-on-a-paintbox-how-to-keep-up-with-mouse-movements-without-delay)

I was going to at some point ask the question of how to repaint only part of a paintbox without invalidating the whole paintbox, which is slow when there is a lot of drawing going on or in my case when there are a lot of tiles drawn on screen.

From the link above [Peter Kostov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962893/peter-kostov) did touch on the subject briefly in one of his comments:

> you can partly BitBlt the offscreen bitmap (only regions where it is changed). This will improve the performance dramatically.

I have limited graphic skills and have never really used `BitBlt` before but I will be reading more about it after I post this question.

With that said, I wanted to know how exactly could you determine if regions of a bitmap have changed? Does this involve something simple or is there more magic so to speak involved in determining which regions have changed?

Right now I am still painting directly to the paintbox but once I draw to the offscreen buffer bitmap my next step is to optimise the painting and the above comments sound exactly like what I need, only the determining regions that have changed has confused me slightly.

Of course if there are other ways of doing this please feel free to comment.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to keep track of the different portions of the screen and while the mouse is moving, use your own mechanism to detect which portion the mouse is over, and re-draw only that part. There's nothing built-in that knows what portions of the graphic are which - the language only knows the pixels. Once you draw it to the canvas, the canvas has no acknowledgement of, for example, a box drawn to it. You have to track all that yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use [`BitBlt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370.aspx) directly if you draw to an offscreen `TBitmap`, you can use `TCanvas.CopyRect()` instead (which uses [`StretchBlt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145120.aspx) internally).  But either way, when you need to invalidate just a portion of the `TPaintBox` (the portion corresponding to the section of the offscreen bitmap that you drew on), you can use [`InvalidateRect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145002.aspx) directly to specify the appropriate rectangle of the `TPaintBox`, instead of calling `TControl.Invalidate()` (which calls `InvalidateRect()` with the `lpRect` parameter set to NULL).  Whenever the `TPaintBox.OnPaint` event is triggered, `InvalidateRect()` will have established a clipping rectangle within the canvas, any drawing you do outside of that rectangle will be ignored.  If you want to manually optimize your drawing beyond that, you can use the `TCanvas.ClipRect` property to determine the rectangle of the `TPaintBox` that needs to be drawn, and just copy that portion from your onscreen bitmap.

The only gotcha is that `TPaintBox` is a `TGraphicControl` descendant, so it does not have its own HWND that you can pass to `InvalidateRect()`.  You would have to use its `Parent.Handle` HWND instead.  Which means you would have to translate `TPaintBox`-relative coordinates into `Parent`-relative coordinates and vice versa when needed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to take charge of the painting in order to do this:

- Call `InvalidateRect` to invalidate portions of a window.
- When handling `WM_PAINT` you call `BeginPaint` which yields a paint struct containing the rect to be painted.

All of this requires a window, and unfortunately for you, `TPaintBox` is not windowed. So you could use the parent control's window handle, but frankly it would be cleaner to use a windowed control.

You could use my windowed paint control from this question as a starting point: [How could I fade in/out a TImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21790393/how-could-i-fade-in-out-a-timage) Use the `ClipRect` of the control's canvas when painting to determine the part of the canvas that needs re-painting.

Comment: If you want to ask a new question please do. I don't see how that comment relates to this answer.

Comment: I noticed the Paintbox canvas has a handle (in Lazarus at least) but is it fair to say that a canvas handle is totally different to a control handle?

Comment: Well, what is a control handle? An HWND. In Delphi a canvas handle is an HDC. I don't see the relevance to this answer though. Where are we going here?

Comment: We are going nowhere :) Because everyone said paintbox does not have a handle which is true, when I saw in Lazarus it has a canvas.handle I somehow figured that the Lazarus variant may indeed have a handle after all - But I figured the handle is completely different and I guess I was just looking for some clarification :)

Comment: A delphi paint box is not windowed. It paints onto its parent's surface.