# Is there a GetMouseMovePointsEx function in Lazarus?

Tags: delphi, lazarus

In this other question I asked: [Drawing on a paintbox - How to keep up with mouse movements without delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509235/drawing-on-a-paintbox-how-to-keep-up-with-mouse-movements-without-delay).

The function `GetMouseMovePointsEx` was brought to my attention by [Sebastian Z](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2292460/sebastian-z), however in Lazarus I am unable to  find this function.

He mentioned that in Delphi XE6 it is in `Winapi.Windows.pas`, in Lazarus though it is not in `Windows.pas`.

I understand Lazarus is by no means an exact copy of Delphi but this function sounds like it could be the answer I am looking for in that other question. Im just having a hard time finding where it is and even getting any Delphi documentation on it. I do have Delphi XE but right now it is not installed and my project is been written in Lazarus.

I did a *Find in Files...* search from the Lazarus IDE targeting the install folder and the only result that came back was from one of the fpc sources in:

> lazarus\fpc\2.6.4\source\packages\winunits-jedi\src\jwawinuser.pas

I  am not sure if I should use the above unit or not, or whether Lazarus has a different variant to `GetMouseMovePointsEx?`

Does anyone using Lazarus have any experience with `GetMouseMovePointsEx` and if so where can I find it?

Thanks.

Comment: You have found it. The jwawinuser.pas unit comes from JEDI library and there's no reason to not use it. Well, of course only if you are targeting Windows platform because that unit (and function) is platform specific.

Comment: @TLama you got me thinking, if I use the `Windows.pas` in a Lazarus project does this also mean the program wont run on other platforms?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.  64-bit Windows excluded.

Comment: @Blobby Of course. As soon as you start calling Win32 API functions directly you tie yourself to Win32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example using Delphi. What you still need to do is filter out the points you've already received.

```
type
  TMouseMovePoints = array of TMouseMovePoint;
const
  GMMP_USE_HIGH_RESOLUTION_POINTS = 2;

function GetMouseMovePointsEx(cbSize: UINT; var lppt: TMouseMovePoint; var lpptBuf: TMouseMovePoint; nBufPoints: Integer; resolution: DWORD): Integer; stdcall; external 'user32.dll';

function GetMessagePosAsTPoint: TPoint;
type
  TMakePoints = packed record
    case Integer of
      1: (C : Cardinal);
      2: (X : SmallInt; Y : SmallInt);
  end;
var
  Tmp : TMakePoints;
begin
  Tmp.C := GetMessagePos;
  Result.X := Tmp.X;
  Result.Y := Tmp.Y;
end;

function GetMousePoints: TMouseMovePoints;
var
  nVirtualWidth: Integer;
  nVirtualHeight: Integer;
  nVirtualLeft: Integer;
  nVirtualTop: Integer;
  cpt: Integer;
  mp_in: MOUSEMOVEPOINT;
  mp_out: array[0..63] of MOUSEMOVEPOINT;
  mode: Integer;
  Pt: TPoint;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Pt := GetMessagePosAsTPoint;

  nVirtualWidth := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN) ;
  nVirtualHeight := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN) ;
  nVirtualLeft := GetSystemMetrics(SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN) ;
  nVirtualTop := GetSystemMetrics(SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN) ;
  cpt := 0 ;
  mode := GMMP_USE_DISPLAY_POINTS ;

  FillChar(mp_in, sizeof(mp_in), 0) ;
  mp_in.x := pt.x and $0000FFFF ;//Ensure that this number will pass through.
  mp_in.y := pt.y and $0000FFFF ;
  mp_in.time := GetMessageTime;
  cpt := GetMouseMovePointsEx(SizeOf(MOUSEMOVEPOINT), mp_in, mp_out[0], 64, mode) ;

  for I := 0 to cpt - 1 do
  begin
   case mode of
     GMMP_USE_DISPLAY_POINTS:
       begin
         if (mp_out[i].x > 32767) then
            mp_out[i].x := mp_out[i].x - 65536;
         if (mp_out[i].y > 32767) then
            mp_out[i].y := mp_out[i].y - 65536;
       end;
   GMMP_USE_HIGH_RESOLUTION_POINTS:
     begin
      mp_out[i].x := ((mp_out[i].x * (nVirtualWidth - 1)) - (nVirtualLeft * 65536)) div nVirtualWidth;
      mp_out[i].y := ((mp_out[i].y * (nVirtualHeight - 1)) - (nVirtualTop * 65536)) div nVirtualHeight;
     end;
   end;
  end;

  if cpt > 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(Result, cpt);
    for I := 0 to cpt - 1 do
    begin
      Result[I] := mp_out[I];
    end;
  end
  else
    SetLength(Result, 0);
end;

// the following is for demonstration purposes only, it still needs some improvements like filtering out points that were already processed. But it's good enough for painting a blue line on a TImage
procedure TForm1.Image1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
var
  MMPoints: TMouseMovePoints;
  Pt: TPoint;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Image1.Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlue;
  MMPoints := GetMousePoints;

  for I := 0 to Length(MMPoints) - 1 do
  begin
    Pt.x := MMPoints[I].x;
    Pt.y := MMPoints[I].y;
    Pt := Image1.ScreenToClient(Pt);
    if I = 0 then
      Image1.Canvas.MoveTo(PT.X, pt.y)
    else
      Image1.Canvas.LineTo(PT.X, pt.y);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: just tested your demo in Lazarus and seems ok. A note to anyone else you need these units adding to the interface section: `jwaWinUser` and `jwaWinType`. I will try and implement into my program now and see if the results are good, thanks.

Comment: Surely the question was about how to gain access to the function rather than to provide a demo of how to call it.

Comment: That is why I had included the GetMouseMovePointsEx definition. But I guess I must have missed something else.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan this is my mistake, the question somehow got crosslinked with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509235/drawing-on-a-paintbox-how-to-keep-up-with-mouse-movements-without-delay

Answer (score 1):

This function is implemented as part of the Win32 library. It is no more a Delphi or FPC function than it is a C++ or VB function. You import it from Win32.

In Delphi, this importing is achieved by way of the declaration of the function in the `Windows` unit. If you examine the source of this unit you'll find lots of type and constant declarations, as well as functions. The functions are typically implemented using the `external` keyword which indicates that the implementation is external to this code. The `Windows` unit is what is known as a header translation. That is it is a translation of the C/C++ header files from the Win32 SDK.

So you need a header translation with this function. The JEDI header translations are the most usual choice. And it seems that you've already found them. If the versions supplied with FPC serve your needs, use them.

Sometimes you might find yourself on the bleeding edge of progress and need to use a function that has not been included in any of the standard header translations. In that scenario it's usually simple enough to perform the translation yourself.

Comment: I try would to copy the definition from jwawinuser to own source and let it use windows unit types. At least that gives you a fighting chance on win64. The Jedi headers are not really 64-bit clean, at least not the version that FPC ships.

Comment: @Marco But they compile right? In which case you only have a problem when you call a bogus translation. Just the same as Emba's translations which are also not 64 bit clean!

Comment: The thought behind this is that many 64-bittisms are in the packing of record types, and fields that scale with pointer instead of with integer (either because wrongly translated, or based on older SDKs and restated in later SDKs).  I don't know the (64-bit) state of Embarcadero's Windows unit. I did one 64-bit service with XE3, and that is about it, the rest of the work apps are 32-bit. To my best knowledge, the FPC Windows unit is better in that respect than the JEDI units in the FPC distro.